# Why was my flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flagging, declined-flags

I recently flagged this question: [Did Jesus visit Jagannath Temple of Puri?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2246/did-jesus-visit-jagannath-temple-of-puri)

as off-topic for this site. However, my flag was declined, and I'd like to understand why.

In my opinion, this question seems to be more about the events in the life of Jesus than anything related to the practices or beliefs of the Hindu religion. The question seems to be asking for a factual answer, and I do not see how any answer to this question would inform someone's understanding of Hindu philosophy or traditions.

Perhaps I am mistaken (obviously at least one person thought so), but could someone please clarify where I am wrong in my line of thinking?

Comment: On the other hand, with respect to the actual declination, the question seems within topic & ok, and is well written. Thank you  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I see what happened over there.

**Technical Reason**

You have insufficient reputation to cast a close vote and hence you flagged the post as Off-Topic. Now, when you flag as off-topic, it gets listed in the [close review queue](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/close/2055).

So when I reviewed that post, I didn't see any reason to close that question(will explain why) so I clicked on leave open button which resulted in flag decline.

[image: Close Review Queue]

---

**Now why I chose *Leave Open*? - Decline Reason**

If you see, the user has researched well before posting his question. He is asking for a scripture reference for what he read in a book to confirm. The question is rather skeptical but still its not off-topic.

*The question seems to be asking for a factual answer* - Yes, as I said the question is somewhat skeptical but that doesn't make the question off-topic.

Its similar to me or you asking a question like *"Is Avatar X an Avatar of lord Vishnu?"* which is not off-topic. If our scriptures mention Jesus then we can certainly answer that question and if no, then we can answer a simple **no** with some details.

Comment: Hmm... I still feel like this question could be better suited for the Christian site, especially since Jesus is not considered a Hindu leader. At the end of the day, the question still feels more like a historical one asking for a reference in Hindu scripture as opposed to a question on Hindu philosophy or practice. That being said, I do understand where you're coming from and I suppose it's enough in the grey area that it probably doesn't make a difference either way.

Comment: @Akshay Umm yea but still the question is on topic [as decided before](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/198/), and we also discuss history on the site as well. Apart from that the question will be suitable to migrate to Christianity.SE IF user wants bible reference but here he is asking for Hindu scriptures... that makes a difference..

Comment: Yeah, I see your point there. The request for citations in Hindu scriptures is probably the main thing that says it can belong here. I guess it was just enough in the gray area to confuse me.

Comment: @Akshay Yea, I was confused myself at first place as I never came across your flag but later found the issue using mod tools...